# NoSuchMethodError when calling getDeclaredAnnotation()

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

I have a running application where once I clicked on a **'Edit'** link of a table, I'm getting an error in the log of `NoSuchMethodError` and the control stays in the current page, not proceeding to the edit page.

Below piece of code has been hit while getting the error;

```
Field[] fields = entityObj.getClass().getDeclaredFields(); 
    for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
        Field field =fields[i];         
        field.setAccessible(true);  
        if(field.getDeclaredAnnotation(EmbeddedId.class)!=null){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

In the above code at the line,
`if(field.getDeclaredAnnotation(EmbeddedId.class)!=null)`
I'm getting the particular error.

Also mentioning the log as below;

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotation(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;
    at com.sprint.neo.querymodel.common.QueryObjectUtil.checkEnitityIsHasEmbeddedId(QueryObjectUtil.java:131)
    at com.sprint.neo.querymodel.common.EntityManager.getEntityObject(EntityManager.java:89)
    at com.sprint.neo.querymodel.common.EntityManager.loadEntityObject(EntityManager.java:72)
    at com.sprint.neo.querymodel.common.EntityManager.entityload(EntityManager.java:60)
    at com.sprint.neo.querymodel.common.EntityManager.loadAndGetEntityObject(EntityManager.java:56)
    at com.sprint.neo.querymodel.common.QueryObjectUtil.getListOfEntityObject(QueryObjectUtil.java:718)
    at com.sprint.neo.querymodel.common.QueryObjectCache.excuteUpdate(QueryObjectCache.java:251)
    at com.sprint.neo.querymodel.common.QueryObjectRow.excuteUpdate(QueryObjectRow.java:298)
    at com.sprint.neo.engine.controller.actions.TaskViewEditAction.edit(TaskViewEditAction.java:83)
```

The control should proceed to the **edit jsp** page as all the jsp are implemented correctly.
What I'm doubting about the error from the log is that, if any **jar** file is missing regarding Reflection api.
Please suggest me a solution to overcome this problem. Any valuable advise will be helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No @Clijsters, it's actually `java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.getDeclaredAnnotation` method that has been invoked here. It's existing api.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the method `Field.getDeclaredAnnotation(Class)`. This method was introduced in Java 8. It is not available in Java 7 and earlier. You need to upgrade your JDK.

`Field` is a subclass of `AccessibleObject` and inherits the method from that class. See [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#getDeclaredAnnotation-java.lang.Class-): It says “Since: 1.8” which is the version for Java 8 in the internal numbering scheme.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable suggestion @cygri . Hope this will work perfectly. Thanks.